# CSS/JavaScript — Make Bootstrap's input boxes look and function like MDL's text field

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, material-design-lite

I'm cuztomizing Bootstrap with their given source code and I came here to ask how to make Bootstrap's input boxes to look and function just like the Material Design Lite's [textfield](https://getmdl.io/components/#textfields-section) component.

> **So why not use MDL then?**
>
> The two frameworks are great in terms of design but I prefer to use
>   Bootstrap for its simplicity, while MDL makes a long coding which I
>   dislike.
>
> **Why not use a theme then?**
>
> I'm customizing Bootstrap myself so I will not be needing a
>   theme here. But instead, this project I'm making will be inspired
>   by the works of those devs.

All I currently have is the base style of the input boxes (my demo is [here](http://jsbin.com/hapaxigune/edit?output)). What I want to achive is the floating labels that acts as a placeholder and the `border-bottom` color that glows from the middle to the left and right (similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26726436/css-bottom-border-transition-expand-from-middle)).

> **I thought I found the solution**
>
> I've searched a lot on the internet relevant to the topic and claimed to
>   have the answer to my question but I prefer not to use it for some
>   reasons. I've found them from [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/google-material-design-input-boxes-in-css3) tutorial site and the similar
>   implementation for Bootstrap from [this](http://codepen.io/zavoloklom/full/yaozl) CodePen demo.
>
> The reason is:
>
> - You have to add two `<span>` element for the `border-bottom` color animation to work which I don't like.
> - A bug for `<input type="email">` that if the required characters are not present, the floating label will return as a placeholder and since
>     it's absolutely possitioned, it surpasses the present texts on the
>     field.
>
> I've made a [demo](http://jsbin.com/zuyicowemi/edit?output) of it to let you see what is actually happening.
>
> **Just having thoughts**
>
> Fez Vrasta's [theme](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/bootstrap-elements.html) for Bootstrap has achieved all this, but I
>   don't know which codes are used from the [source code](https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design). If anyone knew of it please make a sample demo cause it is actually what I want to achieve.

CSS `background-image` and `gradient`, `:before` and `:after` states with `transition` and/or `animation` is what I'm expecting for this but I don't know how. I am also aware of using JavaScript for this but although I've studied Java programming, I know less about JavaScripting.

I've stated it all here so please don't give a simple answer, I need a real code from a kind-hearted person.

Thank you.

Comment: have you looked at [http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/bootstrap-elements.html#forms](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/bootstrap-elements.html#forms) ?

Comment: @ArpitVasani Yes I already have that link on my question.